# json is parsed as null

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, json-deserialization, system.text.json

I have a json structure like below.

```
{"data":{"accountType":"New"}}
```

The model for this is as follows.

```
 public class Data
 {
     public string accountType { get; set; }
 }
```

Below is how I am parsing this data using System.Text.Json.

```
string json2 = "{\"data\":{\"accountType\":\"New\"}}\n";
var account = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Data>(json2);
```

but `account` is parsed as `null`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You're ignoring the first level. The code you have is assuming that the accountType is top level which would look like `{"accountType":"New"}`. You'll need to make a new class with a property of type `Data` named `data`. Fun fact, in Visual Studio, if you copy the raw JSON and go to `Edit > Paste Special > Paste JSON As Classes` it will create the structure for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a root class

```
public class Root
 {
     public Data data { get; set; }
 }
public class Data
 {
     public string accountType { get; set; }
 }
```

and code

```
var account = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Root>(json2);
```